# Spring Boot .mustache file extension

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, mustache

I'm working on a spring boot application and adding a small configuration web page using Mustache templates using [this article as an example](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/21/the-joy-of-mustache-server-side-templates-for-the-jvm).  I have it working fine when all of my mustache template files have the extension .html, but the problem is that I don't get any IDE support.  IntelliJ IDEA has a plugin for mustache, but the extension has to be .mustache.  When I change the file extensions, though, I end up with a 404 error.

I've seen in the [official example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-mustache/) that they are using .mustache, so I know it's possible.  I couldn't find anything in that project to indicate that a setting was changed to enable this.  The only major difference is that I am using Kotlin instead of Java, but I don't see why that would have any effect on the mustache file extensions.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Spring Boot documentation ([for v1.5.6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties), [for v2.0.0.M3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)) you can easily configure the extension of Mustache template files by setting the following property:

```
spring.mustache.suffix=.mustache # Suffix to apply to template names.
```

In v1.5.x the default was `.html` but in v2.0.0 they switched to `.mustache`. ([release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#mustache-templates-default-file-extension))

Also you can configure IntelliJ IDEA to handle `*.html` files with the [Handlebars/Mustache](https://github.com/dmarcotte/idea-handlebars) plugin by registering `*.html` pattern in **Settings > Editor > File types > Handlebars/Mustache**.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer in place of ones already given. Really it should be a comment, but I can't upload a screenshot in a comment.

It's worth noting that (at least in my IDE), I had to install the mustache plugin (not noted in the [kotlin spring tutorial I'm following](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/)), and once installed, there is not a context menu selection for a new mustache file type:

[image: no mustache file context menu option]

But, if you pick the generic `File` and name it `whatever.mustache`, the editor will apply the mustache language tool to it.

[image: format applied]

Seems very "yeah, duh", but it threw me for a bit b/c everything in intellij so far feels so specific, I thought the fact that I wasn't seeing it as an option meant I was missing something :| .

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I just realized that it is a 2.0.0 branch of spring boot and the 1.5.x branch still has it as .html.